# POST Arduino sensor values to local Sqlite db via Flask API

Tags: python, c++, flask, arduino

I have an Arduino script that takes in boolean values from a light sensor attached to my MKR1000.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi101.h>

char ssid[] = "networkname";        // network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "networkpassword";    // network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;            // network key Index number (needed only for WEP)

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
char server[] = "192.111.1.11";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
WiFiClient client;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(6, INPUT);

   //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only

   while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
   Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
   Serial.println(ssid);
   // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
   status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
   delay(10000);
  }

  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 5000)) {
    Serial.println("connected to server");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 192.111.1.11");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  }
}
}

void loop()
{
  bool gotLight = (digitalRead(6) == LOW);

  if (gotLight == 1) {
  String PostDataTrue = "TRUE";
  client.connect("https://192.111.1.11/5000/lights/1",5000);
  client.println(PostDataTrue);
   }

  if (gotLight == 0) {
  String PostDataFalse = "FALSE";
  client.connect("https://192.111.1.11/5000/lights/0",5000);
  client.println(PostDataFalse);
  }

//  Serial.println(gotLight);
  delay(1000); 
}
```

And I also have a Flask script for running a basic API and Sqlite DB.

```
from flask import Flask
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/lights/0')
def hello_world():
    return 'lights off!'

@app.route('/lights/1')
def hello():
    return 'lights on!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

DATABASE = '/Users/reallymemorable/Desktop/reTest.db'

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    return db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()
```

I think most of the .ino file is correct, but I don't know how to get the part inside `void loop()` to make `POST` requests to my API rather than just producing outputs in my serial monitor--which is what currently happens.

Basically, I want my Arduino to continually post new data to the Sqlite DB.

I'm so new to this that I'm not sure what steps to try next and would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Does the flask work?

And, `https://192.111.1.11/5000/lights/1` is correct?

If the port is 5000, `https://192.111.1.11:5000/lights/1` will be correct.

Comment: Thanks for catching that port issue.  Fixed.  The Flask works in that I can access the lights on and lights off pages, but I have not successfully tested any DB functionality.